# Struggling to get Parameter Passing working on JavsaScript

Tags: javascript, function, parameter-passing

I have a problem with this code where I can't get the alert to work and I am unsure how that is. I am trying to practice parameter passing and I cannot seem to get this working or even understand the logic. If anyone can help me, I would be much appreciated, thanks.

Here is my code below:

```
function cardNumber(a, b){
cardTotal = a + b;
return cardTotal;
}

let cardRange = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var cardOne = cardRange[Math.floor(Math.random()*cardRange.length)];
var cardTwo = cardRange[Math.floor(Math.random()*cardRange.length)];
var cardSum = cardNumber(cardOne, CardTwo);

function displayresult(){
    alert("Your card total is", cardTotal, "!");
}

displayresult(cardTotal);
```

Comment: a) `cardTotal` should be a local `var` inside the `cardNumber` function b) you'll want to use`cardSum` in the last line c) your `displayresult` function does not declare a parameter but you're passing an argument d) `alert` takes a single string, not multiple arguments - you will have to use `"…" + number + "!"` or `\`…${number}!\``

Comment: What parameter would I put in for displayresult?

Comment: You can name the parameter anything you want, it'll be the variable that you use in your `alert` statement (currently named `cardTotal`, which is ok, but you need to understand that it's independent from the `cardTotal` that is - should be - declared locally in `cardNumber`).

Comment: function cardNumber(a, b){
var cardTotal = a + b;
return cardTotal;
}

let cardRange = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var cardOne = cardRange[Math.floor(Math.random()*cardRange.length)];
var cardTwo = cardRange[Math.floor(Math.random()*cardRange.length)];
var cardSum = cardNumber(cardOne, CardTwo);

function displayresult(cardSum){
    alert("Your card total is" + cardSum + "!");
}

displayresult(cardSum);



Okay, I have done this now and it still doesn't work, what would my problem here be?

Comment: I'm getting a "*Uncaught ReferenceError: CardTwo is not defined*" in [the devtools console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) caused by the capitalisation typo.

Comment: I think you understood the concepts, now you just need to [learn how to use a debugger](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) to figure out the small mistakes that cause something to go wrong

Comment: Oh, I see my problem now, I declared cardTwo as "CardTwo" in the code which completely ruined it, thanks for helping me out!